# Sitecore - hard coding item ids

Tags: sitecore

Is there any problem retrieving item (pages) by item id?

The only scenario I can think where they might change is if the client deletes a page and re-adds it ...

Normaly we use TDS or a db copy to update our database

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no problem accessing items by ID.  It is the preferred method since the path can change more easily than the ID.  An author is more likely to rename or move an item (or an ancestor) than they are to delete and recreate it.

We usually have one item per installation (or sometimes per site) that contains many treelist fields that point at other key items (e.g. search results page, other settings items, etc.).  We store the ID for this global links item int a config file, then set up a model class for it using Glass Mapper or Custom Item Generator.  That allows us to get nice syntax like this:

```
var searchPage = ClientName.Configuration.Settings.GlobalLinks.SearchResultsPage;
```

Comment: Ben's approach is the same we use with our teams.  In addition, since you are using TDS, you can use the T4 generation template to generate your classes or IDs based on the items you are source-controlling in your TDS project.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem retrieving by id. They are best used for unique contants within the scope of what you are using them for. Within your code, there is an issue of readability but you can create a static IDs class which mitigates this. See the `Sitecore.ItemIDs` and `Sitecore.TemplateFieldIDs` as examples.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid an over-reliance on using item IDs if possible, though as the other answers have stated, this will work. If you do this, its wise to consider setting the security restrictions on any items whose IDs are referenced in code, to prevent users from deleting them (this doesn't prevent users from editing them though).

Another option can be to use template IDs instead. It's quite straightforward to write a few extension methods that will retrieve items/descendants by template id and this can make your solution more robust.